# Firestore security - Allow read if user's uid equals document's field value uid

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to only allow reads to some documents if the user's uid matches the document's uid.

`resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid`

The security simulator gives me this errror for this line.

> Error: simulator.rules line [20], column [16]. Null value error.

Is this a functionality that is just not supported by Firestore security rules?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire rule, not just one expression.  Also please explain how exactly you're using the simulator, and the data you're working with.

Comment: Hi Doug! I have seen some of your videos! I realized I was using the simulator wrong by putting a wildcard document rather than an exact document ID. Thanks for you tip!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, I think you want something like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow list, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow get, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.id == request.auth.token.email;
    }
  }
}
```

This code should allow users to create their own documents and access/edit only them.

Also, `list` allowance is required to check if the document exists before creating it, so apparently it needs to be allowed to all authenticated users.

Note that `resource.id` is actually the document's name. So it means that when you create a document, its name must be the user uid. And of course, you won't be able to have more than one document per collection for the same user.